# C# Linq - Order by with conditional value and return grouped results

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I need to order a result set from EF based on a column which can contain a `.` in some of the values. I want the results grouped by whether it contains a `.` or not, then sorted by name.

Given the following data in a column:

```
6010
6020
6.16.30
7030
6.16.40
7.15.20
```

The result with a .OrderBy(x => x.Column) returns the following:

```
6.16.30
6.16.40
6010
6020
7.15.20
7030
```

However i want to group every result that contains . by themselves and sorted induvidually like so:

```
6.16.30
6.16.40
7.15.20
6010
6020
7030
```

How can I achieve this using Linq?

Comment: Given your description, it really sounds like you want `OrderBy(does-it-contain-a-period).ThenBy(name)`. Have you tried implementing that? If so, what does your attempt look like, and what were the results?

Comment: Yeah... That's exactly what I want, I tried .OrderBy(x => x.Column?.Contains(".")), but it doesn't work with null conditional operator, which made me think I couldn't put boolean checks in there. Stupid ^^

Null-check because the column can also be null.

Thanks :)

Comment: @JonasMohammed You're on the right track - in what order do null values go? Do you need _another_ sort expression for nulls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [possible solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ayy52p):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myList = new List<string>{"6010", "6020", "6.16.30", "7030", "6.16.40", "7.15.20"};
        var result = myList.Select(i => new { Item = i , Counter = i.Count(j => j == '.')}).OrderByDescending(i => i.Counter).ThenBy(i => i.Item).Select(i => i.Item).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join('\n', result));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered. But just wanted to share another possible solution:

```
var finalList = new List<string>();
var givenLst = new List<string> { "6010","6020","6.16.30","7030","6.16.40","7.15.20"};
finalList.AddRange(givenLst.OrderBy(_ => _).GroupBy(f => f.Contains(".")).SelectMany(t => t));
```